# Pong game in tkinter, Check for the ball hitting the vertical paddle

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to implement a pong game in python tkinter. I have paddle on the left side of the canvas and I want to detect the collision of the ball with that paddle. I am unable to get the collision detected properly as sometimes the ball just passed through the paddle. please any help is appreciated , Below is the code for the collision detection i used, not sure whats wrong with it. I am trying to implement is if the ball position is between paddle top and bottom and between left and right then there is collision

```
def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    """ pos(left, top, right, bottom)"""
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.shape)
    if ball_pos[1] >= paddle_pos[1] and ball_pos[1] <= paddle_pos[3]:
        if ball_pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and ball_pos[2] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: [canvas.find_overlapped](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) can give list with all elements which overlap ball. If there is paddle then you have collision. Probably you could do it in one line of code: `return (self.shape in self.canvas.find_overlapped(*ball_pos))`

Comment: Thank you I will try this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there are some rare cases when the ball could pass through the paddle.

The first if statement checks for the y position of the ball and paddle. This should return true iff any part of the ball is in between `paddle_pos[1]` and `paddle_pos[3]`.

The second if statement checks for the x position, and has the same logic. You need to check if the LEFT side of the ball is within range since the that's the part of the ball that will hit the LEFT paddle.

Try out this code:

```py
def hit_paddle(self, pos):
     """ pos(left, top, right, bottom)"""
     paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.shape)
     if ball_pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and ball_pos[1] <= paddle_pos[3]:
         if ball_pos[0] >= paddle_pos[0] and ball_pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
             return True
     return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ball_pos[1]` is the y coordinate of the lower left vertex of the ball's bounding box, Shouldn't you also put a constraint on the y coordinate of the upper-right vertex of the ball's bounding box? For example, if the ball is just bellow the lower end of the paddle I think your code won't count it as a hit.

Hope this helps!